The minimum and maximum value statistics obtained using ee.Reducer.minMax() are inconsistent with those displayed in QGIS
Today, when I was working, I encountered a very puzzling issue. I exported the IBI index calculated in GEE and tried to view it in QGIS, but I was surprised to find that the minimum and maximum values statistics from GEE were inconsistent with those displayed in QGIS. However, when I opened the data in ArcGIS Pro, the values matched those from GEE. I want to know why this discrepancy occurs. I suspect that it might be due to the fragmented ROI region, which could have led to background values or some outliers. If I want to get the same results as in QGIS, can GEE achieve this? Here is my code, https://code.earthengine.google.com/5014e1d96b3cc842afcf520399ae8ce3?noload=true
// roi
var roi1 = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/cloud-project-433203/assets/AUS/grid_33');
var roi = roi1.geometry();
Map.centerObject(roi, 8);

// apply ScaleFactors
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}

// remove cloud
function moveclouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  var cloudMask = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(cloudMask);
}

// function date
var startYear = 2014;
var endYear = 2015;

// cycle
for (var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++) {
  var startDate = year + '-11-01';
  var endDate = year + '-12-30';

  // select data
  var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
             .filterBounds(roi)
             .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
             .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 60)
             .map(function(image) {
               return image.set('year', ee.Image(image).date().get('year'));
             })
             .map(moveclouds)
             .map(applyScaleFactors);

  // median calucate
  var medianImage1 = L8.median().clip(roi);
  var medianImage = ee.ImageCollection([medianImage1]);

  // NDVI、IBI compute
  var L8imgCol = medianImage.map(function(img) {
    // NDVI
    var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B4']);
    img = img.addBands(ndvi.rename('NDVI'));

    // IBI
    var ibi = img.expression(
      '(2 * SWIR1 / (SWIR1 + NIR) - (NIR / (NIR + RED) + GREEN / (GREEN + SWIR1))) / (2 * SWIR1 / (SWIR1 + NIR) + (NIR / (NIR + RED) + GREEN / (GREEN + SWIR1)))',
      {
        'SWIR1': img.select('SR_B6'),
        'NIR': img.select('SR_B5'),
        'RED': img.select('SR_B4'),
        'GREEN': img.select('SR_B3')
      }
    );
    img = img.addBands(ibi.rename('IBI'));

    // SI
    var si = img.expression(
      '((SWIR1 + RED) - (NIR + BLUE)) / ((SWIR1 + RED) + (NIR + BLUE))',
      {
        'SWIR1': img.select('SR_B6'),
        'NIR': img.select('SR_B5'),
        'RED': img.select('SR_B4'),
        'BLUE': img.select('SR_B2')
      }
    );
    img = img.addBands(si.rename('SI'));

    // NDBSI
    var ndbsi = (ibi.add(si)).divide(2);
    return img.addBands(ndbsi.rename('NDBSI'));
  });

  // select bands
  var ibiBand = L8imgCol.first().select('IBI');
  var ndbsiBand = L8imgCol.first().select('NDBSI');
  var ndviBand = L8imgCol.first().select('NDVI');
  
  // calculate indexs
  var minMax1 = ibiBand.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 30,  
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });
  
  var minMax2 = ndbsiBand.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 30,  
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });
  
  var minMax3 = ndviBand.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 30,  
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });

  // print
  print('ibi range for ' + year + ':', minMax1);
  print('ndbsi range for ' + year + ':', minMax2);
  print('ndvi range for ' + year + ':', minMax3);
  // vis
  //Map.addLayer(ibiBand, {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['white', 'gray', 'black']}, 'IBI for ' + year);

  // export
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: ndviBand,
    description: 'ndvi_' + year,
    scale: 30,  
    region: roi,
    crs: "EPSG:4326",
    maxPixels: 1e13,
    fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
  });
}





I set up the symbology in QGIS as follows, and the band range of the TIFF file opened in QGIS matches the range calculated in GEE.

Thank you very much, now my display is consistent. I’m also wondering why this issue occurred. Is it because, at the beginning, QGIS simply estimated based on the histogram and did not calculate the raster?

The default range in QGIS is [2%, 98%], so the displayed range does not match the actual range. Maybe this can help you https://docs.qgis.org/3.40/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html#minmaxvalues

Thank you, I will read it carefully, with gratitude.
